# .NET DLL in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I have spent the last 2 days trying to get a basic VB.NET dll that created to work in VBA.  I have read every single post on this sight but i keep getting the same error.

1. I create a VB.NET class (I run Visual Studio's as administrator).

My class

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text  
Imports System.Runtime.Interposervices
Imports System.Linq

Public Class TestClass
Function TestMethod(ByVal input as String)
    Return "Hello" & input
End Function
End Class
```

2. I set "Make assembly comes visible"
3. I set "Register for COM interop"
4. I build and release the dll
5. I open Excel and add a reference to the dll.

Everything works great so far

6. In a sheet I add the below code

   ```
   Public Sub test()
       Dim a As TestClass 'Note: Auto fills in once i start typing it in so i know that the DLL there 
       Set a = New TestClass  
       MsgBox (a.TestMethod("World")
   End Sub
   ```

When i try running the code I get the following error

> "ActiveX component can't create object"

I have tried this using 2 computers: Win7 64 bit, Excel 2010 64 bit ,VS 2010 and Win7 64 bit, Excel 2013 , VS 2010 64 bit with know luck.  I have read people receiving the same error but I nothing seems to work.

Does anyone see any mistakes in my method?

Comment: It should be Namespace.ClassName or you have to register an assembly using REGASM.EXE DLLNAME.dll and use DIM objNAME as CLASSNAME

Comment: sorry i left that part out because i made a random class name.  I do use the correct syntax you described.  I have used REGASM.EXE and it is successful.  I get the same error though.

Comment: You did not register it correctly.  Nobody can guess why when you say absolutely nothing about it.

Comment: When i build the release the reference is added.  I have also tried referencing the .TLB directly.  The reference is checked and I am able to see my class in the drop down.  So the reference seems to be working.  But, im not sure how i get the error.

Answer (score 3):

-add a namespace to your code.
-make the function as `public`. 
-make it com visible and set 'Register for COM interop' as you mentioned.
-your code should be like:

```
Namespace X
    Public Class TestClass
        Public Function TestMethod(ByVal input As String)
            Return "Hello" & input
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

-build your project, you will find a yourProjName.tlb file in \bin\debug or \bin\release.
-open Excel and add a reference to the yourProjName.tlb not to dll.
-modify your code to be like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim testObj As New TestClass
    Dim myStr As String
    myStr = testObj.TestMethod("ssssss")
    MsgBox myStr
End Sub
```

This worked for me.
**EDIT #1** 
-I am working on Windows 7 32 bit, Office 2010 professional 32 bit with SP2, Visual Studio 2010 with framework 4.
-configure your project for x64 : from Visual Studio ->Go to the Build Menu ->click Configuration Manager -> Under Active solution platform, click New, then add one with x64 as the platform. Use this platform to compile for x64 , [link](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/support/documentation/dotnet/n_distribute_configure.htm) . 
-It is preferred to sign your assembly (very easy) : Project Properties > Signing > Sign the assembly > New -> Enter the name of the file as myKey.snk , no need for password.
-build your project.
- if you are working on the same machine that visual studio in running, then no need to register your assembly, because VS will do since we set 'Register for COM interop'.
-for other client machines where VS in not running, you must register your assembly, take the DLL file only, run cmd as administrator, run the following command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase /tlb "D:\out\VB_DLL_001.dll"
```

Note that this command will generate the *.tlb file for you in the same folder. 
-add your dll to Global Assembly cache by running the following command in cmd (that is running as administrator) :

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\gacutil.exe" /i "d:\out\VB_DLL_001.dll"
```

-from Excel add reference to the generated tlb file : VBA Editor -> Tools -> References -> Browse -> Select the tlb file -> OK . Then run the previous code, I hope it will run successfully .
 
**EDIT #2** 
Based on the comment, It works by building the DLL for **x64** architecture, So, no need for other steps in EDIT #1.

Comment: Thank you for your info, i added all your comments and I still get the same error. When i cycle through the code the error occurs as "myStr=testObj.TestMethod("ssss") Run time error 429 Activex component cant make object. Any chance you can create your code and see if it runs?

Comment: Could it have to do with using the 64 bit version of excel?

Comment: @Chipper14 : I modified the answer. Could you please take a look.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.  I appreciate the time you took to write that out.

Comment: THANKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK YOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU.  Building it using x64 worked!!!!!!  I was told leaving it any CPU was the way to go.  I guess thats wrong, maybe its an excel 2013 issue.. Thanks again, you are awesome

Comment: @Chipper14 : You are welcome, Thanks for your feedback about the problem, (I modified the answer EDIT #2).

Answer (score 0):

I have fought this exact same battle many times and still am not completely sure what exactly needs to be done to make this work but I will pass along my most recent experience.

Having built my dll exactly as you described building yours,  it worked fine in vba on the same machine I did the initial development on....seems to be because visual studio gets the registration of the dll exactly  correct.  It also worked when I copied it to the c:/windows/system32 directory and using the Regam.exe from the framework64 directory in Microsoft.net
However,  when I tried to do the same on another machine,  it looked like it registered ok but when the vba code executed it said it could not create the activex object.  I moved the dll to the syswow64 dir and I used the reasm.exe from the framework directory instead of the framework64 directory and then it worked.