# C# COM interop DLL in Excel VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba, dll, com-interop

While trying to build a DLL for use in Excel VBA from an already existing DLL source I got stuck in one of the first steps.

The source looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ZCon
{

    public class ZConsts
    {
        #if __MonoCS__
             public const string ZLibrary = "zcon.so";
        #else
             public const string ZLibrary = "zcon.dll";
        #endif
    }

    public class ZClient
    {

        [DllImport(ZConsts.ZLibrary)]
        protected static extern int WriteIt(IntPtr Client, int Len, byte[] Buffer);
        public int WriteArea(int Len, byte[] Buffer)
        {
            return WriteIt(Client, Len, Buffer);
        }

    }

}
```

I'm not exactly sure about the the 'DllImport' in relation to the namespace.

The assembly should be COM-visible and Visual Studio registers for COM interop. Now i want to register it on another system with RegAsm.exe.

I've got Framework/v4.0... and Framwork64/v4.0..., 64-bit Windows and x86-Excel-2013.

First I tried Target System: Any CPU and the registration with RegAsm.exe only works with the Framework64 version ('Types registered successfully').

**RegAsm.exe ZConCOM.dll /codebase**

also tried

**RegAsm.exe ZConCOM.dll /tbl:ZConCOM.tbl /codebase**

Now I want to set the reference within the VBA editor and DLL as well as TBL are not displayed in Windows/system32 (via 'Browse' in 'References').

Another attempt with x86 as Target System in Visual Studio also failed.

Comment: Hi downvoter, could you give me a hint. I really don't know how to approach this. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea why this has been down voted - hopefully the person responsible will explain their actions...

Comment: I hope my answer on the following link will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27588801/992406

Comment: Thank you for the link to and the time you put into this detailed answer!